# How do you do a clean install of emacs+auctex?

Tags: auctex, install

It was established [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/confused-about-emacs-vs-emacs-d-init-el?noredirect=1#comment73927_47944) there is a problem with my installation of emacs. So I did

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove emacs
```

and remove all in

```
$ locate emacs | grep conf
```

I reinstalled emacs from source (configure, make, make install). In the process, I had to do:

```
$sudo apt-get install emacs24-common
$sudo apt-get install libotf-bin
$sudo apt-get install libm17n-0
```

As this point I can get emacs to start. Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install auctex
```

But the list of problems never ends. A suggestion?

```
$ sudo apt-get install auctex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
auctex is already the newest version (11.88-1.1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up emacs24 (24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1) ...
Install cmake-data for emacs24
install/cmake-data: Byte-compiling for emacs24
>>Error occurred processing cmake-mode.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/cmake-data/cmake-mode.el"))
Install emacsen-common for emacs24
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs24
>>Error occurred processing /etc/emacs24/site-start.d/00debian-vars.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/etc/emacs24/site-start.d/00debian-vars.el"))
>>Error occurred processing /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/debian-startup.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/debian-startup.el"))
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs24 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of auctex:
 auctex depends on emacs24 | emacs-snapshot; however:
  Package emacs24 is not configured yet.
  Package emacs-snapshot is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package auctex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs24
 auctex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Other info:

```
$locate emacs
```

[output](https://jpst.it/1C1W0)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't install emacs using apt you should install AUCTeX with the emacs package manager or from the source package https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-unix.html